# WMSGetFeatureInfo : No feature found on click

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

My map displays well my WMS layers. When i try to get the feature info, the debugger tells me no feature is found `features: Array[0] , length :0`

I don't know if it is because of a projection issue: map is in 4326, original data is in 27563 ; 
or if it comes from geoserver.

Here is my simplified code:

```
function init(){

        map = new OpenLayers.Map({
          'map'});

        var base_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(base_layer);
wmsLayers = {
            'Poly':{
                geoserverName: 'workspace:name'
            },
            'Point':{
                geoserverName: 'workspace:name2'
            }
        }

        var geoserver = {
            url: 'http://X.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/geoserver/wms',
            options: {
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    displayInLayerSwitcher:true,
                    singleTile:false,
                    opacity:0.5
                }
            };

        wmsLayerList = [];

        for (var wmsLayerType in wmsLayers) {
            wmsLayer = wmsLayers[wmsLayerType];
            // Create layer for each wmsLayer
            olwmsLayer = wmsLayers['layer'] = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                wmsLayerType,
                geoserver.url,
                {
                layers: wmsLayer.geoserverName,
                transparent:true,
                format: 'image/png'
                },
                geoserver.options
            );

            // add layer to map
            map.addLayer(olwmsLayer);

            // add to layer list
            wmsLayerList.push(olwmsLayer);
        }

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

        highlightLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Highlighted Features", {
            displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
            isBaseLayer: false
            }
        );
        map.addLayer(highlightLayer);

        infoControls = {
            click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: geoserver.url,
                title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                layers: wmsLayerList,
                queryVisible: true
            }),
        for (var i in infoControls) {
            infoControls[i].events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
            map.addControl(infoControls[i]);
        }

        infoControls.click.activate();
    function showInfo(evt) {
        alert(evt.xy.x +', '+ evt.xy.y +', length: '+ evt.features.length);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

geoserver log:

```
Request: getFeatureInfo
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@XXX, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@XXX]
    GetMapRequest = 
GetMap Request
 version: 1.1.1
 output format: image/png
 width height: 603,460
 bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[X : X, X : X]
 layers: XXX
 styles: green,line
    XPixel = 405
    YPixel = 232
    FeatureCount = 10
    InfoFormat = text/html
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    PropertyNames = null
    Get = false
    RawKvp = {INFO_FORMAT=text/html, BBOX=X, X, X, X, QUERY_LAYERS= XXX, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=460, REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo, STYLES=,, WIDTH=603, FEATURE_COUNT=10, VERSION=1.1.1, FORMAT=image/png, LAYERS= XXX, Y=232, X=405, SRS=EPSG:4326}
    BaseUrl = http://X.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/geoserver/
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.1.1
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
```

Comment: do you have a proxy?

Comment: Yes i do, and i can find the connexion request in my geoserver log.

Comment: Can you capture the GetFeatureInfo request that is made in OpenLayers (using something like Fiddler).  Then make that same request directly in browser.  Do you get a valid response?  If so the problem isn't with GeoServer

Comment: It looks like your bounding box is broken, there should be numbers there not X X X X and your query_layers as XXX looks odd too, if you have only one layer then you should only have one style. If you are just hiding stuff please don't as the name of your layers and the bbox don't tell us anything, but could well be the source of the error